# gamecenter dialog language doesn't get localized

Tags: localization, sandbox, game-center

I change the language of my device something different than English, but GameCenter dialogs still appear in English. I mean:

Sign in to Game Center

Use Existing Account

Create New Account

Cancel

Welcome back xxx!

etc...

Game Center app works perfectly in localized device language, but dialogs in my app is still in English.

I suppose those messages and menu texts should appear in device language? Am I wrong?

I can't find anything on Apple refs about this.

Is this happening beacuse I am in sandbox mode?
Or do I need to set GC language in the project?

I tried restarting device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found it. My assumption is wrong in the first place.

Gamecenter messages and menus are not affected by the device language but, by the xib's localization.

I just edited the xib file's folder which is localized in english by default.

renamed  en.lproj  >>   xx.lproj  (here xx is the local language code)
and readded files to the project.

All gamecenter messages and menus are in local language now.